# syntax error when assigning to command result to variable

Tags: bash, testing

I'm doing some basic unit testing with the shunit2 unit test framework. 
I'm getting the error " syntax error near unexpected token `nodeError=$( node "node_fake_returns/return_error.js" )" on the first line of my function. the function is as follows:

```
function testHandleNodeReturnError{
    nodeError=$( node "./node_fake_returns/return_error.js" )    
    if [ grep -i "Error" <<< "$nodeError"  ]; then
        assertTrue "true"
    fi
}
```

It is suppose to run a node script that returns an error message to stdout, then assign that output to a variable. Only this first line in the function is important.

I'm quite new to bash and I've messed with the formatting of this line, mostly just adding spaces in different places, but I can't seem to find what's causing the syntax error. This is probably pretty simple but if somebody could show me what might be wrong I would be greatful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By pasting your code to [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) I was left with:

```
function testHandleNodeReturnError{  
                                  ^-- SC1095: You need a space or linefeed between the function name and body.
```

Which is quite literal. You need a space there.

> function testHandleNodeReturnError

Using `function` keyword is [deprecated](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete). Just use `function_name() { function_body; }`.

> if [ grep -i "Error" <<< "$nodeError"  ]; then

This is very wrong. This is outputting the content of `nodeError` variable to standard input of `[` command. The `[` is a command, a executable, just like `grep`,  it's an alias to [`test`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) program. Then it runs `[` comamnd with `grep`, `-i`, `"Error"` and `]` as 4 of it's arguments. You don't want that. If you want to check for `Error` string, just use `grep`'s exit status:

So do:

```
testHandleNodeReturnError() {
    nodeError=$(node "./node_fake_returns/return_error.js")
    if grep -q -i "Error" <<<"$nodeError"; then
        assertTrue "true"
    fi
}
```

Comment: You can also simplify this a little by removing the `nodeError` variable, and just using `if node "./node_fake_returns/return_error.js" | grep -q -i "Error"; then`